# SQL WHERE IF clause issue

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL/Java code issue. The basic overlay is as follows: a MySQL database with a table. In this table there are multiple columns. One column consists of names. An associated column is months. In the third column there is counts. So a sample table would be

```
john - january - 5
john - january - 6 
mary - january - 5
Alex - February- 5
John - February - 6
John - February - 4
Mary - February - 3
John - march - 4
```

The table continues to month May.

So John appears in five months, Mary in 3, and Alex in one. Currently, my SQL query somewhat looks like this.

```
    select name, sum(count)/4 
    from table where (category ='something' 
    AND month not like 'May') group by name;
```

Basically, what this query is supposed to do is just display each name with the average counts per month. Hence, the sum will be divided by four (because I exclude May, so it must divide Jan-April/4). However, the issue is that some names only appear in one month (or two or three).

This means for that name, the sum of the counts would only be divided by that specific number, to get the average counts over the months. How would I go about this? I feel as if this will require some if statement in a where clause. Kind of like where if the count of the distinct (because months may repeat) is a certain number, then divide the sum(count) by that number for each name?

Also, I think it may not be a where if clause issue. I've read some forums where possibly some use of case could be utilized?

Comment: is it mysql or sql-server?

Comment: "a mysql database" I believe it's just tagged incorrectly.

Comment: Mysql database. I apologize I messed up on the tags. I'm new to this and not sure on how everything works. If I mess up anywhere else please let me know. I want to be able to ask for help the best way possible in the future.

Comment: Have you considered using the `AVG()` function?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for each name N you want SUM(count) / M where M is the number of months that actually have a count for name N ?

Comment: I was thinking about it. Look at my below comments for my concerns over using this function. Thank you.

Comment: Amine... yes. Absolutely. You nailed it. That is exactly what I want. But my syntax/sql skills are not there yet. This seems complex for me. Amine, do you know how I would go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need average per month, you can GROUP BY name and month and use AVG function:

```
SELECT `name`, `month`, avg(`count`)
FROM table 
WHERE `category` ='something' AND `month` NOT LIKE 'May'
GROUP BY `name`, `month`;
```

If you need average for all period, just GROUP BY name and AVG count:

```
SELECT `name`, avg(`count`)
FROM table 
WHERE `category` ='something' AND `month` NOT LIKE 'May' 
GROUP BY `name`;
```

And another option, if you don't like `AVG`:

```
SELECT `name`, sum(`count`)/(SELECT count(*) FROM `table` AS `t2` WHERE `category` ='something' AND `month` NOT LIKE 'May' and `t1`.`name` = `t2`.`name`) 
FROM `table` AS `t1` 
WHERE `category` ='something' AND `month` NOT LIKE 'May')
GROUP BY name;
```

But I would stay with `AVG`.

Actually, i prefer to use `!=` instead of `NOT LIKE` it's improves readability

Comment: I would use the average function. But my issue is this. There can be many records in the database with the same month. January can appear fifteen times, February ten, and so on. For my purpose, I need the average count per month. If I use the avg function doesn't it get the averages over the number of records?

Comment: And if not would it still get an average over only the number of months that actually appear? Like alex appeared in one month, so his average should just be that value, because it should be divided by one. Mary should be divided by three. John by four (because only going from Jan-April).

Comment: @user3794422 Nope, it will devide only by number of elements in group, not total. So you can use it(Or test at least, to see if it works)

Comment: Thank you so much man. Yes, I tested this out. Which is what I should have done before questioning it's merits. It works like a charm. I apologize to the forum if this question had been asked already. I couldn't find any duplicates though. Again, thank you Uriil and to everyone else who responded. Amine, thank you as well. I appreciate it.

Comment: Don't know what a subquery is. So I cannot really comment if it seems like "overkill". I don't want to trouble you with asking why this is bad, unless you have the time for it. :) all help is appreciated.

Comment: @user3794422 Just compare second and third queries. Output is same , but third query almost twice longer. And i believe that second one will work faster(but not sure)

Comment: if you want to test things you can look at my post with the sql fiddle... Amine's answer is calculating each persons total average. Uriil's answer is calculating the monthly average (average of instances per month)

Comment: @Uriil those queries don't have the same output. In the second query you're calculating the average count per record, only the last one actually answers the question.

Comment: @Amine no.. his first answer answers the question.. the OP wants an average per month per person

Comment: @JohnRuddell that's not what he says in the question comments.

Comment: @Amine look at the first comment in this answer... `For my purpose, I need the average count per month` I believe in the question comments the OP mis understood what you were asking. because in his post he also says `Basically, what this query is supposed to do is just display each name with the average counts per month.`

Comment: @JohnRuddell good catch, this is pretty confusing. But you can deduce all kinds of meanings from that...

Comment: @Amine i honestly don't know what the OP wants now lol... he said that your query works too?? but its different than this one...

Comment: @JohnRuddell when he said "average counts per month", I think he didn't mean "per month" as in "give me a breakdown per month", but rather a synthetic number as in "miles per hour"...

Comment: Yea I dono i threw in some random queries just for fun regardless lol

Comment: Okay. I am sorry for all of the confusion. I will see if I can be more precise. So

Comment: There's the names, counts, and months. As I have said, there are duplicate values. Sometimes a name may be duplicated in one month, sometimes there will be many names in a month. Things like that. Look at the above list for an example. Anyways, the query I wanted would somehow take the sum of the counts for the name (name of person) and divide by the total distinct months the person shows up in. So.. Alex has a sum total count of 5, but he only showed up one month (in above list). So 5 divided by 1 should leave him five. John's total count is 25 and three months, so 25/3. These averages are

Comment: what I wanted the query to show. The name with the associated average count per month. When I run the second post by uriil and the query by you amine, I get the same results... for whatever reason.

Comment: Ah makes much more sense now.. you wanted a total average instead of a monthly average. the second query only groups by name and not by month also which is why its giving you the total average.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completness sake here is a [WORKING FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b862/1). using the AVG function is the way to go as it will do the average per person per month. look at John in January.. his result is 5.5 when the count (in january) is 5 and 6.. average = 5.5.

```
SELECT 
  person, 
  month, 
  avg(counter)
FROM testing 
where 
(
  category ='something' 
  AND month <> 'May'
) 
GROUP BY person, month;
```

If you want to see the data in one like as it sounds like that from your post then you can do this. [ANOTHER FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c623a/1)

```
SELECT
    person,
    group_concat(month),
    group_concat(average_count)
FROM(
    SELECT 
      person, 
      month, 
      avg(counter) as average_count
    FROM testing 
    where 
    (
      category ='something' 
      AND month <> 'May'
    ) 
    GROUP BY person, month
      ) as t
group by person;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT name, SUM(count) / COUNT(DISTINCT month)
FROM table
WHERE month != 'May'
AND category = 'something'
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: This one works as well. It generates the same results as Uriils. His second code actually does the same as this one? This is odd because he said that one would be for the entire period. Either way both work...

Comment: No way his second query does the same as this. Please read my comments on his answer.